# Can I ask about whether a solution is possible in car transmission?

Tags: discussion, scope

I want to ask whether a given solution is possible or no, I don't have an issue with my car, I just to ask if a given solution to a theoretical problem is possible or no.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, theoretical automotive questions are on-topic for this Stack.** Just ensure you have enough detail in the question to ensure it is answerable. Also, please understand what you are thinking may not be what's going on or what could happen, so have an open mind as far as to what the answer may be.

**Note:** Please use the [theory](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theory) tag when posting your theoretical question, which should be used in conjunction with whatever area of the vehicle you are wondering about (ie: [transmission](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transmission) or [automatic-transmission](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automatic-transmission) or whatever).

Comment: Thank you sir :)